# Dstroke package problem: "Unknown archive file size"

Tags: miktex

I have a problem to load the dstroke with the Miktex 2.9 package manager.

I refreshed FNDB, updated formats in the settings and synchronized the package manager. I did this multiple times and I also tried other mirrors.

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: Unknown archive file size.
Data: package="dstroke"
Source: libraries\miktex\packagemanager\internal.h
Line: 497
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit, build 10586
Invokers: non-existing/explorer
SystemAdmin: no
PowerUser: no
... file paths ...
```

This problem was also reported in the EDIT part of the question:
[Miktex 2.9 problem installing dsfont.sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324718/miktex-2-9-problem-installing-dsfont-sty)

I put this a as new question, as the latter was mainly a synchonization problem. My problem was solved there 'manually', which I cannot reproduce (file names, url?). Although, I couldn't comment there as a new user.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is no dstroke package, the font is in "doublestroke". If you see a dstroke package in the manager your package manager is not correctly synchronized.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thank you! Doublestroke solved it. My original problem was the dsfont.sty was not found, and I looked for the error cause. I somehow caused the problem to the wrong (old) package on my search. Synchronisation: I figured out a file permission error on a .fndb file with the update manager. Maybe because of a Win7-->Win10 update. Thanks again for the hint!